# open alertdialog when click on the marker in google maps in android studio

Tags: android

I already added multiple marker in google map. But when I click on the particular marker, it should show dialog containing some message and selection button.How to get this?

Answer (score 1):

You should do like @Vurtne says. 
Here you can see many another interesting things what you can do with markers. 
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MarkerDemoActivity.java
It can be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

By creating a class with all the information you want to show in dialog box, you can solve the problem. Just use the marker id as a key to that information so you can get specific data from the class.

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

```
    mMap = googleMap;

    //here I'm using Firebase but you can add marker statically or from any other source
   mList.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
       double location_left, location_right;


       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            int count = 0;

           for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               String rightLocation = child.child("lat").getValue().toString();
               String leftLocation = child.child("lon").getValue().toString();
               String city = child.child("city").getValue().toString();
               String deg = child.child("deg").getValue().toString();
               String speed = child.child("speed").getValue().toString();

                location_left = Double.parseDouble(leftLocation);
                location_right = Double.parseDouble(rightLocation);


               Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location_right, location_left)).title(city).snippet("Wind Speed: "+speed).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.wlll)));

                //adding all the information in LocationDetails class with marker id so I can get the specific information, but you can store the data in sqlite db or anything
               locationDetailses.add(new LocationDetails(marker.getId(), location_right, location_left, city, Double.parseDouble(deg), Double.parseDouble(speed)));

           }
           LatLng position = new LatLng(88.0433, 92.66942);
           mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position));


            //Here setting onClickListener on mMap object of GoogleMap
           mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
               @Override
               public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Map_Activity.this);
                    //searching marker id in locationDetailses and getting all the information of a particular marker
                   for (int i = 0; i<locationDetailses.size(); i++) {
                        //matching id so, alert dialog can show specific data
                       if (marker.getId().equals(locationDetailses.get(i).getMarkerID())){
                           builder.setTitle("City: "+locationDetailses.get(i).getCity());
                           builder.setMessage("Wind Speed: "+locationDetailses.get(i).getSpeed()+"\n"+"Degree: "+locationDetailses.get(i).getDeg()+"\n"+"We can plant WindMill here");
                       }


                   }

                       builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               // User clicked OK button
                           }
                       });
                       builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               // User cancelled the dialog
                           }
                       });

                       // Create the AlertDialog
                       AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                       dialog.show();


                    // Add the button

                   return false;
               }
           });


       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using google map on clicklistener you can open alert dialog**

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                       alertDialog();
                    }
                }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onMarkerClick and get the marker info like this:

```
yourMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
@Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
           return false;
        }
    });
```